Is the Schwartz semi-norm a norm?
In the script for my lecture, there is an exercise asking for a proof that
$$
\|\varphi\|_{\alpha, \beta} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} |x^{\alpha} \partial^{\beta}\varphi(x)|
$$
is not a norm on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. The solution says that $\varphi \equiv 1$ is a counterexample for positive-definiteness because $|x^{\alpha} \partial^{\beta}\varphi(x)| = 0$ for $\beta \geq 1$, so $\|\varphi\|_{\alpha, \beta}=0$. However, I don't understand why $\varphi$ should even be an element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, given that $x \cdot \varphi(x)$ is not bounded. I also found this post where the user apparently asks for a proof that $\| \cdot\|_{\alpha, \beta}$ is a norm, at least on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Other posts however talk about how the Schwartz space isn't even normable and call $\| \cdot\|_{\alpha, \beta}$ merely a seminorm.
Now I am very confused. Is $\| \cdot\|_{\alpha, \beta}$ a norm on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ or not?

It is a norm, as the answer to your linked question explains. You're right about why the counterexample in your script isn't valid.
However, this norm doesn't capture the Schwartz topology, since it neglects the behavior of derivatives greater than $\beta$ and decay exponents greater than $\alpha$. (To be more precise, convergence in this norm is strictly weaker than convergence in the Schwartz topology.) This is the sense in which $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is not normable.
